# Как определить сложность алгоритма в коде?

Tags: javascript, сложность

хочу понять какая в данном случае сложность алгоритма

```
 if (isSunday(startOfMonth(today)) === true) {
      for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        const element = array[i];
        firstWeek.push(element);
      }
      for (let i = 7; i < 14; i++) {
        const element = array[i];
        secondWeek.push(element);
      }
      for (let i = 14; i < 21; i++) {
        const element = array[i];
        thirdWeek.push(element);
      }
      for (let i = 21; i < 28; i++) {
        const element = array[i];
        fourthWeek.push(element);
      }
      if (format(lastDayOfMonth(today), "dd") > "28") {
        if (format(lastDayOfMonth(today), "dd") === "28") {
          for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            fivethWeek.push(<span className={styles.notVisible}>10</span>);
          }
          for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            sixthWeek.push(<span className={styles.notVisible}>10</span>);
          }
        }
        if (format(lastDayOfMonth(today), "dd") === "29") {
          for (let i = 28; i < 29; i++) {
            const element = array[i];
            fivethWeek.push(element);
          }
        }
        if (format(lastDayOfMonth(today), "dd") === "30") {
          for (let i = 28; i < 29; i++) {
            const element = array[i];
            fivethWeek.push(element);
          }
          for (let i = 29; i < 30; i++) {
            const element = array[i];
            sixthWeek.push(element);
          }
          for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            sixthWeek.push(<span className={styles.notVisible}>10</span>);
          }
        }
        if (format(lastDayOfMonth(today), "dd") === "31") {
          for (let i = 28; i < 29; i++) {
            const element = array[i];
            fivethWeek.push(element);
          }
          for (let i = 29; i < 31; i++) {
            const element = array[i];
            sixthWeek.push(element);
          }
          for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            sixthWeek.push(<span className={styles.notVisible}>10</span>);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: сложность в зависимости от чего?

Comment: в данном случае сложность `O(1)` - так как количество операций константно

Comment: @Grundy Cпасибо большое, я так и думал, но не понимал влияет ли вложенность if на сложность, еще раз спасибо)

Comment: Код сложный, его можно упростить и сократить в три раза. Например: `for (let i = 28; i < 29; i++) {` сложно написано.